Grub still can't detect CentOS install after update-grub in Ubuntu
I have an old PC (Dell Optiplex 990) that I'm trying to repurpose into a Linux machine to get more familiar with Linux.
I'm setting it up as a dual boot machine (Ubuntu 22.04, CentOS 7). The system is BIOS Legacy MBR.
I already installed Ubuntu 22.04 (with its own /boot partition on /dev/sda1 and root (/) on sda2. Bootloader on /dev/sda.
I then installed CentOS, /boot is on sda3 and root (/) on sda4. I deselected the bootloader installation on this one  since I didn't want to override the one already installed bootloader when I installed Ubuntu earlier.
I then went to boot Ubuntu and did the changes for grub to be able to detect my CentOS installation; enabled OS prober and updated grub sudo update-grub.
However, grub still can't detect my CentOS installation and doesn't list it, it only shows Ubuntu options in the grub boot menu.
Does anyone know what the issue might be and the workaround for it? Thank you so much.

I went for a workaround instead (used CentOS grub bootloader and grub instead).
I went to install CentOS grub bootloader in the MBR (replaced Ubuntu'a grub) via live USB grub-install. I'm now using CentOS' grub2.
For some reason, Ubuntu's grub-mkconfig and os-probe is able to find the kernel of CentOS but wasn't able to write them into the /boot/grub/grub.cfg config when I tried to check after executing sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg. (note, I've already set GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false in etc/default/grub).

When I installed CentOS' grub, I was able to find my Ubuntu install from CentOS using grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg and os-probe was able to find and write the detected Linux installs into /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
I also just installed 2 other distros (Debian 11, Fedora 38) and was able to successfully add them to CentOS' /boot/grub/grub.cfg and can boot into those distros successfully.
